# Scale UIBezierPath for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, transformation, uibezierpath, adaptive-ui

I want to understand what's the correct way to scale shapes of bezier curves for
different screen sizes. Say, I've made an icon for a `UIButton` using `UIBezierPath`
like this:

```
UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[rectanglePath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(6, 23)];
[rectanglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(23, 23)];
[rectanglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(23, 6)];
[rectanglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(6, 6)];
[rectanglePath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(6, 23)];
[rectanglePath closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[rectanglePath fill];
```

The coordinates have absolute values. How should scale this shape for different
screen sizes?

1. Do I have to parametrize the coordinates? I see this approach as
   difficult because shapes can be very complex.
2. Or maybe I can apply some kind of transformation to a `UIBezierPath` to scale
   it to a size the corresponds to the screen size?
3. Or do I have to create the code with bezier paths for each screen size and
   take it when needed?

Three options and I'm not sure which one is the correct.. Or maybe there is
another option which I don't know yet?

Comment: scale in the sense change the line width or scale the whole bezier path , just like zoom in ?

Comment: @Mr.T scale the whole path. Like we make images 1x, 2x, 3x. But I want to make the icons with code not with graphic assests. Or is it a bad practice?

Comment: yes you can do that with  CGContextScaleCTM and redraw the view!!!